# Does Entity Framework Core remove old columns upon renaming model properties?

Tags: sql, entity-framework-core

First question: in Entity Framework Core (EF Core), if you rename a property in your model, does EF drop the old column in the database? Or does EF simply create a new column with the new name, and leave the old one alone?

Second question: if EF Core does indeed drop the old column, will it warn you if there is existing data that is about to be wiped out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer is - No. It doesn't drop the column.

To verify, I created a model named Book.

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I added a migration and updated the database. I then put a couple of records in the table.

I then changed the `Name` property in the model to `Description`.

When I added another migration, here is the relevant code in the `Up` method.

```
 migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(
    name: "Name",
    table: "Books",
    newName: "Description");
```

This was translated into the following TSQL

```
 EXEC sp_rename N'[Books].[Name]', N'Description', N'COLUMN';
```

So - it doesn't drop and add, it just renames the existing column.

After updating the database again, my records were still there with the values that I had inserted when the column was `Name`.